# How to call a Controller ActionResult method from @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to call a controller ActionResult method from anchor tag without changing the url in MVC3 razor engine.

My url is: "http://localhost:2993/admin/adminindex" and I have one anchor tag "SingOut" and i want to remove my session.

This is my syntax on View page:

```
<div>@Html.ActionLink("SingOut", "signout", "Admin")</div>
```

And on Admincontroller I want  to call this ActionResult method

```
public ActionResult signout()
{
      Session.Abandon();
      return View("~/Views/admin/admin.cshtml");         
}
```

When I click on signout, it always goes to Index ActionResult method.
Is it Possible to call Controller ActionResult method from javascrit not jquery?
I want it only pure javascript not jquery.

Comment: first verify your typos : sing != sign

Comment: i think your requirement is that when you click on sign out button then you wont go in that url "~/Views/admin/admin.cshtml" and you wont to call that url from javascript right ? plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

Abandoning the session will most likely cause a redirect to the index page. The page you are viewing is protected (as far as i understand) so when you sign out you cant stay on the same page. Then why would you do it asynch if the system is redirecting you anyway (or worse you are logged out and showing a page that doesnt work) ?

Comment: it never goes to signout ActionResult

Comment: My point is, why not skip the async javascript part, since when you logout it will redirect you to login, and thats not an async process. Then making a normal ActionLink would solve it. Or am I missing something?